# Why Parameterless factory methods are Leaky Abstraction?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, factory

I'm reading a book which says:

```
// code smell
public interface IProductRepositoryFactory {
   IProductRepository Create();
}
```

*The Dependencies created by an Abstract Factory should conceptually require a runtime value, and the translation from a runtime value into an Abstraction should make sense.
By specifying an IProductRepositoryFactory Abstraction with a parameterless
Create method, you let the consumer know that there are more instances of the given
service, and that it has to deal with this. Because another implementation of IProductRepository might not require multiple instances or deterministic disposal at all,
you’re therefore leaking implementation details through the Abstract Factory with its
parameterless Create method.*

I'm a little bit confused here, what does "more instances of the given service" mean, does it mean that you call a concrete Factory's Create method multiple times? what's wrong with that? even if you have factory methods that does have parameters as:

```
public interface IProductRepositoryFactory {
   IProductRepository Create(string type);
}
```

and if you call a concrete Factory's Create method multiple times there will be multiple instances too. so what's wrong with parameterless factory methods? what does it leak?

Comment: https://freecontent.manning.com/dependency-injection-in-net-2nd-edition-abuse-of-abstract-factories/

Comment: I think you would get more out of this process and more valuable information if you just researched this more. Yes we can answer a single question, and potentially give you a great answer, however the process is slow for you, and you are missing all the other relevant information in the process. Secondly, we cant tell you what the author was thinking in the extreme case. Additionally, these are fashion sense questions, where stackoverflow is more about concrete answers and solutions, this is neither and likely better suited to SoftwareEngineering

Comment: I think there are two important points to note when evaluating this excerpt. First is that the advice is specific to the given example. This is not general advice about a pattern, but rather, advice about a specific implementation in a specific context. In other words, the point isn't that parameterless `Create` methods are _all_ leaky abstractions. This example just happens to be one. Second is that this example is _not_ a GoF pattern.  This degenerate form of Abstract Factory is common, but does not satisfy the criteria defined by the book.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To address this question properly really requires reading the [full article](https://freecontent.manning.com/dependency-injection-in-net-2nd-edition-abuse-of-abstract-factories/) for any readers of the answers here to have the necessary context. In terms of the specifics of your particular question, here's some clarification on the concerns that are raised:

1. Injecting the factory instead of the service itself puts the onus of lifetime management of the dependency (`IProductRepository`) on the consumer (`HomeController`). If the dependency was injected instead of the factory, a proxy class or the IoC framework could be charged with lifetime management, freeing up the consumer to focus on working with the API surface of the dependency.
2. Use of a proxy repository class could further limit the leak, as `IDisposable` would no longer be implemented by `IProductRepository` nor exposed to the consumer since the proxy would manage lifetime.
3. The `Create` method of the factory implies that multiple instances of whatever implementation is being handed back can be created. Again, this places extra and unnecessary responsibility on the consumer to manage- or at least be concerned with this when it could be handled elsewhere. As pointed out in Matt's answer there are circumstances where it's perfectly fine- if not expected- to be able to generate more than one instance from a factory. In the article in question it's really a matter of the repository pattern and the conventions that come with it that makes the design awkward; typically it doesn't make sense to have multiple instances of a given type of repository but by injecting the factory instead of the factory instance, the code allows this thus creating the leak.

Overall, most of the concern here revolves around the fact that a factory is being injected as a dependency instead of the dependency itself which ultimately requires more knowledge of the dependency than is necessary on the consumer end. The parameterless factory method returning an abstraction further compounds this. If some runtime information needed to be provided in order for that factory to make a decision as to what concrete type to instantiate and hand back *as an abstraction*, injecting the factory would make more sense. As it stands it's just not great design, and poor design can lead to additional mental overhead. The fact that the `Create` method hands back an interface instance instead of a concrete instance without accepting any parameters might a) raise questions as to why the factory would hand back an instance of one type or another, thus requiring knowledge of how the factory makes its decisions, or b) require knowledge of the fact that there is only one implementation of `IProductRepository`. Neither of these are anything that the consumer, or the developers leveraging the dependency, should really have to concern themselves with. A proper abstraction combined with proper IoC mitigates these concerns.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. For the third point, why multiple instances of whatever implementation is a concern for the consumer other than object lifetime management? The consumer just calls Create and get an instance, then the consumer calls Create again to get a second instance, what's wrong with that?

Comment: @sydevloper  I've elaborated on point 3 based on your comment. Please see the updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

An abstraction is "leaky" when it fails to hide details of the underlying implementation that it is supposed to hide.

It isn't true that a parameterless factory method is *always* leaky, because that of course depends on what the abstraction it returns is *supposed* to hide, and the author you reference never really specifies what information details are exposed that are supposed to remain hidden.

But what he says is often correct.  If you provide this `IProductRepositoryFactory` method, then the receiver can create as many instances of `IProductRepository` as it likes... but *why* would the receiver *want* to make one, or two, or a bunch?  If you pass this factory interface, then the choice is probably important.  The receiver *must know* about the kinds of trade-offs involved in making one instance vs. many.  It probably has to do with caching, thread pooling, etc.

Often, this *is* the kind of implementation detail that the receiver should not have to know about.

**But, you know...**

It is actually pretty common and perfectly fine under many circumstances to inject interfaces that look a lot like this case, and this gets into fussing about the definitions of words.

For instance, you might pass in a factory that the receiver would use like this:

```
factory.createDocument().setTitle(title).setContent(content).save();
```

Perfectly fine.  What's the difference?  Well, in this case it's that the document we're creating is not a "Dependency".  The factory itself is the dependency.  The service it provides is the ability to create documents, which the caller will then *own*.  These documents are obviously stateful and have identity.  This is not something that the `Document` abstraction is supposed to hide at all, and so this is not a leaky abstraction.

Similar patterns happen a *lot* when working with multithreaded code.  You will quite often have a thread-safe factory service that creates objects that are *not* thread-safe.

Answer (score 1):

> does it mean that you call a concrete Factory's Create method multiple times? what's wrong with that?

Well, their point is that you don't know what to do with the product repository. Is it a singleton? Then it should be an actual singleton instance, not coming from a factory. Is it disposable? Well, you're returning a `IProductRepository`, not an `IDisposable`, so there's nothing to suggest that you should be disposing that.

> even if you have factory methods that does have parameters [...] if you call a concrete Factory's Create method multiple times there will be multiple instances too

I believe their thinking is that you'd be getting already built instances based on your parameters that are cached between runs, so there's no disposing involved.

I'm not sure I fully agree with their thinking, but I will say that in my opinion you'll never sell this pattern to me. Either use a singleton, or dependency injection (which supersedes singletons as well).

Comment: The article states that IProductRepository implements IDisposable. They should have had the code for IProductRepository in the article for clarification, but it is stated in the article.